# Write Main Bundle File To NSPasteboard with Swift for macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am writing an application for macOS that will include pre distributed files in the wav format that users will be able to copy from my app to other apps that accept wav files. So lets say there will be a button that when pressed would copy a file from the app's main bundle to the users pasteboard.

I am loading the file with Bundle.main.path(forResource:_) and setting it to a string.

Then I create pasteboard and set it to NSPasteboard.general()

When I then write the string to the pasteboard, macOS copies the file's path to the pasteboard instead of the file itself.

What can I do in order to write the file itself to the system pasteboard? I am using Swift to write this application.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a relatively simple typo in your implementation:  could you cut & paste the code you're using the load the file and copy it into the pasteboard?